# Spark streaming output not saved to HDFS file

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to save the Spark streaming output to a file on HDFS. Right now, it is not saving any file.

Here is my code :

```
StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels();

SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyTestCOunt");
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf,  new Duration(1000));

JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);
JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
                 return  Lists.newArrayList(SPACE.split(x));
                }
      });

JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(
      new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
                 return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
        }
      }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
          return i1 + i2;
        }
  }); 


wordCounts.print();
wordCounts.saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://mynamenode:8020/user/spark/mystream/","abc");
ssc.start();
ssc.awaitTermination();
```

`wordCounts.print()` works, but not `wordCounts.saveAsHadoopFiles`, any ideas why ?

I am running below commands :

1) `nc -lk 9999`

2) `./bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.NetworkWordCount localhost 9999`

Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: Could you please assert that my edit didn't change what you meant ? Also, are you able to connect to your cluster via the spark shell ?

Comment: Well, did you send anything to netcat?

Comment: Yes i had send some data after nc -lk 9999 this command. if i disable  this "wordCounts.saveAsHadoopFiles()" it prints data.

Comment: my hadoop version is '2.3.0-cdh5.0.3' yarn base. so i am compiling with maven with following command 'mvn  -Phadoop2-yarn -Dhadoop.version=2.3.0-cdh5.0.3 -Dyarn.version=2.3.0-cdh5.0.3 -DskipTests clean package'

Comment: In pom i replace <version>${protobuf.version}</version> with 2.5.0,Now it is creating files in HDFS but it doesn't show any data

Comment: I did using Scala it works fine and saved the streaming output in HDFS files...:)

Comment: So,  still the problem for the java version? or is has it been solved too?

Comment: Did you find the solution??

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same problem by specifying `master` as `local[x] x > 1`. If you run master as local, Spark could not assign slot to execute task.
Like

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("conveyor").setMaster("local[4]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`wordCounts.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://mynamenode:8020/user/spark/mystream/", "abc");`

instead:

`wordCounts.saveAsHadoopFiles("hdfs://mynamenode:8020/user/spark/mystream/","abc");`

Answer (score 0):

`JavaDStream<String> lines;`
Initialize lines with our data.

`

```
lines.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
    public void call(JavaRDD<String > rdd) throws Exception {
    Date today = new Date();
    String date = (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(today));
    rdd.saveAsTextFile(OUTPUT_LOCATION+"/"+date+"/");
    }});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing the Sandbox / Server timezone to my local timezone, as my Twitter account has GMT and my Sandbox has UTC. I have used the following commands to change my Sandbox timezone:

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
chkconfig ntpd on
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
/etc/init.d/ntpd start
date
```

I haven't restarted my Hadoop services after the timezone change.